# Does JFrog Artifactory OSS provides private docker registry?

Tags: docker, artifactory, docker-registry, jfrog-cli

I'm aware of JFrog Artifactory Pro for support of private docker registry which we can use to push and pull the docker images from Artifactory. I want to know whether same support is available with Artifactory OSS version also or not.

Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

JFrog offers free Docker/Helm registry, it called JFrog Container Registry and it is based on Artifactory.
More information on JFrog Container Registry and comparison against other Docker registries can be found [here](https://jfrog.com/container-registry/).

Answer (score 8):

**Edit**: the below was true until [20th of November 2019](https://jfrog.com/blog/announcing-jfrog-container-registry/). Since then, @Shay's accepted answer which is younger than mine is correct. The below alternatives are still worth to consider for a free solution.

---

You can have a look at [the jfrog OSS page](https://jfrog.com/open-source/).

From there click "Artifactory" > "Compare to pro".

Scroll down in the list of features to "Package Management", read the overwhelming list of formats the product manages and notice in front of the "OSS" version this little note:

> (Only supports: Maven, Gradle and Ivy)

So there we are, your answer is: **no**

There are several other solutions you can consider if your requirement is "OpenSource and/or Non Paid". I'll only name a few I'm familiar with:

- The original [docker registry](https://docs.docker.com/registry/)
- [Gitlab container registry](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/container_registry/index.html)
- [Nexus repository manager](https://www.sonatype.com/download-oss-sonatype)
- [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/) (for one single image only, paid subscription to go beyond).
- ...

Comment: wow, thanks for correction. :) and good you're tracking or may be got remembered to correct, to help community honestly. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I just spun up an artifactory-oss docker-compose setup and can confirm that it is not included. See screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: Hey @frakman1 it does not but you can download [container registry][1] to use the same for docker registry usage, which is indeed free.

Hope this helps, this same as what shay has responded already, above.


  [1]: https://jfrog.com/container-registry/